# What's the best way to use TinyMCE in an express project?

Tags: node.js, tinymce, express, npm

I'm working on an express project that might need TinyMCE, what's the best way to use TinyMCE in an express project? Do I just follow the installation instructions, is there a special module or set of instructions I should follow? I've searched google, the tinymce forums, and here using the following search terms, nodejs,express,tinymce. Could someone please point me in the right direction? Thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few links which should help you get started -- I found them very useful.

1. http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/%22For_Dummies%22 -- perfect simple explanations here
2. http://www.zenphoto.org/news/how-to-create-custom-tinymce-configurations
3. http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Installation

In general, I've found that if you want something complex like Microsoft Word-style, then just follow the default install instructions. Or, if you want to make it simpler, everything you need, you should be able to change in the tinyMCE.init() function -- that's where you can change what buttons are there, etc.

Comment: Okay, so no special I need to do to get going? That's what I was looking for, thanks!